# How do I use a button to switch between two different graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two different matplotlib graphs that I would like to switch between upon a button press. The code I have will add the second graph below the first graph when the button is pressed but I want it to replace the first graph. This is a somewhat similar stackoverflow question ([How to update a matplotlib embedded into tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53155949/how-to-update-a-matplotlib-embedded-into-tkinter?rq=1)) but I can't seem to get this to apply to my situation.

The graphs that I have coded, graph_one and graph_two, are two simple graphs that I pulled from the matplotlib documentation. In my actual use I have two much more complicated graphs that are very dissimilar, one is a single plot and the other has an additional subplot. Because the graphs I wish to switch back and forth between are so dissimilar it is important to me that the solution be able to handle the graph inputs as separate definitions. It should also be noted that my graphs are embedded in a tkinter widget and it is important that the solution also account for this embedding. 
Here is the code I have:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler



def graph_one():
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='Graph One')

    #plt.show()
    return fig


def graph_two():
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='Graph Two')

    #plt.show()
    return fig

class matplotlibSwitchGraphs:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.embed_graph_one()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def embed_graph_one(self):

        fig = graph_one()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.master)  
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        canvas.draw()

        canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit", 
command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="Switch Graphs", 
command=self.switch_graphs)
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def embed_graph_two(self):

        fig = graph_two()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.master)  
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit", 
command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="Switch Graphs", 
command=self.switch_graphs)
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    def on_key_press(event):
        print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
        key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

    def _quit(self):
        self.master.quit()  # stops mainloop

    def switch_graphs(self):
        self.embed_graph_two()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    matplotlibSwitchGraphs(root)
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It seems like I should be able to use a command like

```
ax.clear()
```

in the switch_graphs def to clear out the first graph but that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm posting updated code to show some small progress I've made as well as to better represent the different nature of the two graphs I wish to switch between. Both graphs are still simple graphs taken directly from the matplotlib documentation but they better represent that one of my graphs is a single plot while the second graph has two plots positioned directly on top of one another.

In my actual case I am trying to use a button to be able to switch between a candlestick chart with a volume overlay and one without the volume overlay. Posting all the code to show the candlestick charts would make for a very long piece of code so I've simplified it by using these simpler graphs. I've also eliminated matplotlib's navigation toolbar for the sake of simplicity. Here is my revised code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler



class matplotlibSwitchGraphs:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.embed_graph_one()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    # the def creates the first matplotlib graph
    def graph_one(self):
        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(t, s)

        ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
               title='Graph One')

        # plt.show()
        return fig, ax

    # This def creates the second matplotlib graph that uses subplot
    # to place two graphs one on top of the other
    def graph_four(self):
        x1 = np.linspace(0.0, 5.0)
        y1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x1) * np.exp(-x1)
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.subplot2grid((5, 4), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)
        ax.plot(x1, y1, 'o-')

        means_men = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
        std_men = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 4), (4, 0), sharex=ax, rowspan=1, 
colspan=4)
        ax2.bar(std_men, means_men, color='green', width=0.5, 
align='center')

        return fig, ax

    # this def takes graph one and embeds it in a tkinter widget
    def embed_graph_one(self):

        fig, ax = self.graph_one()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.master)  
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        canvas.draw()

        canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)


        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit", 
command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="Switch Graphs", 
command=lambda: self.switch_graphs(canvas, fig, ax))
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)


    # This def takes the second graph and embeds it in a tkinter 
    # widget
    def embed_graph_two(self):

        fig, ax = self.graph_two()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.master)  
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)


        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit", 
command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="Switch Graphs", 
command=lambda: self.switch_graphs(canvas, fig, ax))
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    # the def defines the key press event handler
    def on_key_press(event):
        key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)

    # This def quits the tkinter widget 
    def _quit(self):
        self.master.quit()  # stops mainloop

    # This def switches between the two embedded graphs
    def switch_graphs(self, fig, canvas, ax):
        ax.clear()
        self.embed_graph_two()
        canvas.draw()




def main():
    root = Tk()
    matplotlibSwitchGraphs(root)
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code still doesn't replace the first graph with second graph but just places the second graph below the first. Any help on getting this code to replace the first graph with the second would be appreciated.

The graphs that I am plotting are an OHLC candlestick chart and an OHLC candlestick chart with a volume overlay. Unfortunately The

```
self.canvas.draw()
```

command in the draw_graph defs doesn't seem to apply here. When I try to display the graphs all I get is a blank figure. Here is the code I am using that plots the candlestick chart. This would correspond to draw_graph_one.

```
def ohlc_daily_date_axis(self, stock_sym):
    mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)  # major ticks on the mondays
    alldays = DayLocator()  # minor ticks on the days
    weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%b %d %Y')  # e.g., Jan 12 2018
    dayFormatter = DateFormatter('%d')  # e.g., 12

    quotes = get_stock_price_data_list_of_tuples(stock_sym)
    graph_header_text = 'Daily OHLC Candlestick Chart: ' + stock_sym + ' Date Range: ' + str(
        num2date(quotes[0][0]).date()) + ' - ' + str(num2date(quotes[-1][0]).date())

    if len(quotes) == 0:
        raise SystemExit

    self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 5))
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    self.ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
    self.ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
    self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)
    # ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dayFormatter)
    plt.title(graph_header_text)
    self.ax.set_ylabel('Share Price ($)', size=10)

    # plot_day_summary(ax, quotes, ticksize=3)
    candlestick_ohlc(self.ax, quotes, width=0.6)

    self.ax.xaxis_date()
    self.ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
    self.ax.format_coord = self.get_ohlc_from_date_xy
    # ax.fmt_xdata = get_ohlc_from_date_x

    #plt.show()
    self.canvas.draw()
```

How would I modify this to get it to show the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer to include Tk embedding (significant changes from the other answer, so adding new answer instead of editing that one). I moved `graph_one()` and `graph_two()` into the switch graph wrapper class, and renamed them to `draw_graph_one()` and `draw_graph_two()`. Those two new class methods replaced the `embed_graph_one()` and `embed_graph_two()` methods. Most of the content within `embed()` methods were duplicates, and were therefore moved to a `config_window()` method which is called when the class object is instantiated. Created a few class data members to capture the plt variables (e.g. `canvas`, `ax`, `fig`) and created a new data member to keep track of which graph is currently displayed (`graphIndex`) so that we can properly draw the correct graph when `switch_graphs()` is called (instead of calling `embed_graph_two()` every time "switch" is made, as in the original code). Optionally, you can take out `t` from the `draw` methods and make it a class data member (if the values for `t` don't change).

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

# Seperated out config of plot to just do it once
def config_plot():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='Graph One')
    return (fig, ax)

class matplotlibSwitchGraphs:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.fig, self.ax = config_plot()
        self.graphIndex = 0
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.master)  
        self.config_window()
        self.draw_graph_one()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def config_window(self):
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text="Quit", command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="Switch Graphs", command=self.switch_graphs)
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def draw_graph_one(self):
        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        self.ax.clear() # clear current axes
        self.ax.plot(t, s)
        self.ax.set(title='Graph One')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def draw_graph_two(self):
        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s = 1 + np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(t, s)
        self.ax.set(title='Graph Two')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_key_press(event):
        print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
        key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, toolbar)

    def _quit(self):
        self.master.quit()  # stops mainloop

    def switch_graphs(self):
        # Need to call the correct draw, whether we're on graph one or two
        self.graphIndex = (self.graphIndex + 1 ) % 2
        if self.graphIndex == 0:
            self.draw_graph_one()
        else:
            self.draw_graph_two()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    matplotlibSwitchGraphs(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output (two windows, alternating whenever switch graph button is clicked):
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for posting this. It's going to take me a few minutes to work through it.

Comment: This is a thing of beauty. Thank you so much. This works beautifully. Thanks Again!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. I didn't see your edit to your question before posting this answer, so apologies, it's solely based off of your original code. Your hunch was correct in using `ax.clear()` along with using `ax.plot()` to simply plot new points on the same fig.

Comment: The edits I made were just to try and make my code clearer for you and to better help me understand how to pass ax to the switch_graphs def. My edits didn't really change anything conceptually. Thanks again, this was really driving me nuts.

Comment: Unfortunately, my actual graphs don't seem to work with this setup. I've posted the code that corresponds to draw_graph_one. I'm hoping you can look at it and tell me what needs to change so the data can be seen.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'll take a look on Monday when I'm back at work but kinda hard to debug the code without being able to run your example. I think you need to remove the line `self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 5))' into just a `config()` method so that you're not assigning a new `ax` to the class object. You rather want to `clear()` what's plotted in your `self.ax` and `ax.plot()` your new data each time you call your function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions. If I can't get it to work I'll post my complete code (without all the bells and whistles) as a new question and leave a link to the new question in the comments section here so you can take a look on Monday. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Hi, I posted my complete code in a followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151953/while-switching-between-two-different-tkinter-embedded-matplotlib-candlestick-ch  Thanks for all your help. I'll be back online Monday morning. The title of the question is "While switching between two different tkinter embedded matplotlib candlestick charts data does not appear"

Answer (score 1):

Going off of matplotlib's [documentation on buttons](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/buttons.html) and the [stackoverflow question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53241759/how-to-switch-between-diagrams-with-a-button-in-matplotlib), here is the code that does the basics of what you mean. I'm sorry I didn't use your code, but it was just too big of a code block.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

# Button handler object
class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    # This function is called when bswitch is clicked
    def switch(self, event):
        self.ind = (self.ind+1) % len(functions)
        ydata = 1 + functions[self.ind](2 * np.pi * t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        ax.set(title='Graph '+str(self.ind + 1))
        plt.draw()

    # This function is called when bquit is clicked
    def quit(self, event):
        plt.close()

# Store the functions you want to use to plot the two different graphs in a list
functions = [np.sin, np.cos]

# Adjust bottom to make room for Buttons
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)

# Get t and s values for Graph 1
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

# Plot Graph 1 and set axes and title
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
           title='Graph 1')

# Initialize Button handler object
callback = Index()

# Connect to a "switch" Button, setting its left, top, width, and height
axswitch = plt.axes([0.40, 0.07, 0.2, 0.05])
bswitch = Button(axswitch, 'Switch graph')
bswitch.on_clicked(callback.switch)

# Connect to a "quit" Button, setting its left, top, width, and height
axquit = plt.axes([0.40, 0.01, 0.2, 0.05])
bquit = Button(axquit, 'Quit')
bquit.on_clicked(callback.quit)

# Show
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Click "Switch graph" and you get:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your input but I am unable to get this to work in my situation. My graphs are embedded in a tkinter widget and this does not account for that embedding. Or at least if it does I can't figure out how to make it work. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at the Tk embedding tomorrow. Out of time today :(

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I've been banging my head against the wall on this for several days now.

Comment: Can I pass a parameter to `on_clicked`  callback?